# Syntax for timestamp after a designated time

Tags: powerbi, dax

This measure isn't calculating as expected.

```
SumAfter1300 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Fulfillment' ),
    'Fulfillment'[DateCreated] > TIME ( 13, 0, 0 ),
    'Fulfillment'[Status]
        IN { "Awaiting Response", "In Progress", "Routed", "Unresolved" }
)
```

Comment: That's not a useful description of a problem. What do you expect, what are you currently getting, and what does your data look like?

Comment: Currently I expect 0 and am getting 46.  None of the times are beyond 1300.  The data set is only from 7am this morning to 11:30am

Answer (score 0):

```
SumAfter1300 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Fulfillment'),
'Fulfillment'[DateCreated]> today()+ TIME(13,0,0),
'Fulfillment'[Status] IN {"Awaiting Response","In Progress","Routed","Unresolved"})
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: the addition of today() into the code only counts records created this day